# Angular inheritance in factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

In my current project i working with angular in the front for the first time and i having a little problem with extending "classes" true factories.

case: i have 3 types of markers that can be placed on the map.
1. assigned markers.
2. unassigned markers.
3. panned markers.

i have a base marker object

```
engine.factory('marker', ['map','icons', function (map, icons) {

 var Marker = function Marker() {};

 Marker.prototype.mouseover = function mouseover (e) {
  e.target.setIcon(this.icons[this.iconOnHover]);
 };

 Marker.prototype.mouseout = function mouseout (e) {
   e.target.setIcon(icons[this.icon]);
 };

return Marker;

}]);
```

and now i am trying to make the panned marker

```
engine.factory('pannedMarker', ['map', 'marker', 'icons', function (map, marker, icons) {

 var PannedMarker = {};
 PannedMarker.prototype = new marker();

 return function PannedMarker(location, id) {
   this.id = id;
   this.location = location;
   this.icon = 'purple';
   this.iconOnHover = 'purpleHover';

   L.marker(this.location, {icon: icons.purple}).addTo(map.map)
   .on('mouseover', this.mouseover)
   .on('mouseout', this.mouseout);
  };
}]);
```

when i mouse over on my marker i get this error: 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

i not so good at js prototyping and i hope to get some constructed information how to implement this as a best practice. Cause i know this is not the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var PannedMarker = {};
PannedMarker.prototype = new marker();
```

This doesn't make any sense, because an object doesn't have a prototype property (functions do). 
After that you do

```
return function PannedMarker(location, id) {
```

which overrides the variable `PannedMarker` again

Here is an article about javascript inheritance, maybe it helps: [javascript inheritance](http://calje.eu/)